# Flask-mail is trying to user localhost as mail server instead of configured SMTP server

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I am trying to send email from my application using flask mail. I have my setting configured in **init**.py but flask-mail is trying to use 127.0.0.1 as the mail server with port 25 instead of the configuration I have provided

At first I though it was a problem with using gmail. So I tried sendgrid and mailjet with the same results. Then I noticed that it isn't using the correct server

Here is my config from **init**.py

```py
MAIL_SERVER = 'in-v3.mailjet.com'
MAIL_PORT = 587
MAIL_USE_TLS = True
MAIL_USE_SSL = False
MAIL_USERNAME = os.environ.get('MAILJET_USER')
MAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('MAILJET_PASS')
mail = Mail(app)
```

here is the dump() from the stacktrace

```
address 
('127.0.0.1', 25)
timeout 
<object object at 0x7f086826c150>
source_address  
None
host    
'127.0.0.1'
port    
25
err 
ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused')
res 
(, , 6, '', ('127.0.0.1', 25))
af  
socktype    
proto   
6
canonname   
''
sa  
('127.0.0.1', 25)
sock    
<socket.socket [closed] fd=-1, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6>
```

All my other config stuff in **init**.py is being read and applied correctly

Answer (score 2):

Adding app.config was the answer

```py
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'in-v3.mailjet.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 587
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = os.environ.get('MAILJET_USER')
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = os.environ.get('MAILJET_PASS')
```